# AspxGridView: how to update the control from client side

Tags: devexpress

I am using DevExpress v 10.2.

I need an advice: what is a best solution for the following problem.
I have an ASP.NET Web Application. A page there contains an `AspxGridView` control and AspxCheckBox control.
I need the following: when state of the `AspxCheckBox` control is changed, immediately re-load content of the `AspxGridView`.

The reloading may change count of `rows` displayed by the AspxGridView. Additionally, an instance of EditForm may be opened at the moment when `AspxCheckBox` control is changed.

What is a best solution here?

Answer (score 1):

Use [ClientSideEvents.CheckedChanged](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsCheckEditClientSideEvents_CheckedChangedtopic) for handling ASPxCheckBox state change.
For refreshing ASPxGridView use [ASPxClientGridView.Refresh](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewScriptsASPxClientGridView_Refreshtopic).
For closing edit form use [ASPxClientGridView.CancelEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewScriptsASPxClientGridView_CancelEdittopic) method.

You should post your code if you need more info.

Comment: "For opening edit form use ASPxClientGridView.StartEditRow method" - well, I think I should CLOSE EditForm if it is open at the moment, should not I? Otherwise the following situation may happen: a row is not displayed anymore (because of the AspxGridView is reloaded), but its EditForm is still open.

Comment: I misunderstood your last sentence. Anyway, I changed my answer.